# Making the arrow keys function in a WinForm TextBox just like an HTML input field?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The textboxes would be faster to navigate when using arrow-keys if we could get to the end of the bottom line by pressing down, or equivalent move to the beginning of the upper line by pressing up. This is working if you try it in webpage with HTML input or textarea. But for windows forms textbox control it has the same behaviour with notepad. When you press down or up arrow keys it does move the cursor from the end or beginning of the whole text. It should also behave when highlighting text using up and down arrow keys.

Any thoughts on how to implement this in C# or vb.Net? Thanks in advance.

Here is the current working highlighting but only for shift+Down key:

```
if ((keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Down))) {
if (ctl is TextBoxMaskBox) {
    var edit = ctl as TextBoxMaskBox;

    int selectionLength = edit.MaskBoxSelectionLength;
    int remTextLength = edit.MaskBoxText.Length - edit.MaskBoxSelectionLength;
    string remText = edit.MaskBoxText.Substring(selectionLength, remTextLength);

    if (remText.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) == -1) {
        edit.MaskBoxSelectionLength = edit.MaskBoxText.Length;
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Yahia, edited the question and current working code above has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about two different platforms here.  Sure enough, regardless of where you are in the bottom line of a `textarea`, pressing <kbd>DOWN</kbd> does move you to the end of that line.

I would imagine that the majority of people would use the <kbd>End</kbd> key to get to the end of the current line, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> to get to the end of the entire text input area.

This is universal to the web and Windows applications, and I would question how many people even know about the web-specific behaviour.  I suspect most people would transfer their expectations from Windows to the web and continue to use <kbd>End</kbd> etc..

Comment: Our client users wanted this kind of feature the same behavior as with HTML input.

Comment: I don't know why they want this. My thinking is that they get used to html input web control or since our client is Swedish, maybe it is to much for them or difficult to press Ctrl+End or Shift+End using Swedish keyboard. I haven't tried Swedish keyboard though.